# Angular, image not found (GET 404) but it shows image after running ngbuild

Tags: node.js, angular, express, multer

The problem is I have to run `ngbuild` each time after uploading image otherwise  images can not be seen anymore

I have tried to store images somewhere on server other than `/src/assets folder`

```
server\images/image.jpg
```

Now images are stored but I can not see them in browser

**static path**

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'dist/my-app')));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the static path as

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'dist/my-app')));
```

your image needs to be in `dist/my-app/images` folder instead of `src/images` to be able to access it without restarting the server.

You might need the logic to store the image in `dist/my-app/images` folder instead of `src/images` in production environment.

The reason why it is working after doing `ng build` is because it build the required file and copies all the images in the `dist/my-app` folder, so after doing `ng build`, new image is successfully copied in the `dist` folder, and thus it is available for your app.

Comment: how are you uploading images in the src/images folder?

Comment: i have uploaded images through multer in src/assets folder

Comment: thats what i am saying, in your backend code, upload in dist/my-app/images folder instead of src/assets/images folder in production build

Comment: but angular shows only that images that are stored inside src/assets folder

Comment: when you build the angular app, everything gets copied to dist/my-app folder and the location of images folder also changes from src/assets to dist/my-app. Have a look at your dist folder

Comment: thanks #again its working fine without ng build after changing images destination to dist/my-app folder

Comment: Glad i could help